# How do I reference my own record in a model in a Django view?

Tags: django, django-views, django-queryset

I have two models, Contestant and Team, which have a relationship with each other. They are defined like so:

```
class Contestant(models.Model):
    contestant_email = models.EmailField(max_length = 254) 
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    assigned_team = models.ForeignKey('Team', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)  
    
class Team(models.Model):
    team_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    team_description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    team_leader = models.ForeignKey(Contestant, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
```

I'm trying to build a link "My Team", which will show all the contestants on the team of the logged in contestant. I can't hardcode this, so need to get the contestants team in the view somehow so I can filter my queryset.

I got as far as this attempt below:

```
class myteam(LoginRequiredMixin, SingleTableView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = Contestant.objects.filter(assigned_team__id=self.request.user__assigned_team__id)
        return qs
    
    def get_template_names(self):
        return 'xgames/viewteam.html'

    def get_table_class(self):
        return TeamTable
```

I realize my attempt of `assigned_team__id=self.request.user__assigned_team__id` is incorrect, but I also realized I can't see any way to retrieve the team id of the user calling the view and use it to filter my queryset.

This has to be a pretty common use case and I'm sure there is a simple solution, but I haven't been able to figure it out, and searching brings up too many unrelated results.

I have a separate view to view anyteam, which takes a url parameter to bring up any team, but I had the same problem. I couldn't find a way to obtain my own team id for the team i would be assigned to as a contestant and pass it as a link in the templte.

What is the correct approach here?

Comment: @ha-neul No, I am still quite new to django, learning as i go. Reading about it now, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this query will do the trick.

```
def get_queryset(self):
        qs = Contestant.objects.filter(assigned_team=self.request.user.contestant.assigned_team)
        return qs
```

Comment: Works brilliantly, and so simple! So I can reference any foreign key a similar way? Now I know, thank you!

Comment: No, this is only valid for [OneToOne](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/) fields. The structure is a little different in ForeignKeys. From the Contestant object, you could access the user as contestant.user. However, since there can be more than one contestant connected to a user object, you had to query the objects as written in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward).